# Does giving blood affect plane travel?

Tags: air-travel

I have a flight planned from Boston to Hawaii (about 13 hours). I am normally fine on planes, but the longest I've traveled by plane is 4 hours.

I plan on giving blood (a normal whole blood donation, which I am also used to) about a week before the flight. Will that have a meaningful effect on how I feel during the long flight?

Just to be thorough, if I donated blood closer to the flight - say a day or a handful of hours before - would that affect me while flying? Is there any point at which it would be considered unsafe?

Comment: Related on [aviation.se]: [Is there an FAA rule or Advisory Circular with regard to blood donation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39107/3427)

Comment: This is something you should ask your doctor about, since many personal aspects must be taken into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only give my personal experience and non-medical biology teacher's opinion: I have flown within a few days of blood donations several times, both whole blood and platelet. There were no symptoms. A week later, your red cell count might be measurably lower than, say, 60 days later, but unless you plan to run long distances on the plane or something you probably wouldn't notice anything. Flying is just like going to moderate altitude, in terms of your physiology--unless going to Denver would be a problem you will be fine.